# TreeNode when double-clicked is recognized as TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, double-click

I was having problems with handling `TreeNode` double-click event calls, so I had the event code to display a `MessageBox` with the type of the object that was double-clicked. This was the result: 
 [image: MessageBox showing the bug]

The event used was `NodeMouseDoubleClick`, any suggestions?
Using .NET Framework 4.7.2, C# 7.3 and Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1

Comment: Show us the code that displays that messagebox, including the code that retrieves the object you are displaying in the messagebox.

Comment: HideSelection is for when the TreeView does not have focus.  Determines if the "highlight" is still visible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Microsoft's convention for events like these is to put the top-level object in the `sender` parameter of the event, which would be the `TreeView`.  If you want the node you clicked on, look for the [`Node` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs.node?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the [`TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thanks, I used `e.Node` instead of `sender` and it worked